# Finding a a piece of string in a cell and editing that vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Is there a way of looping through all of the cells and if somewhere within a certain cell that contains a certain piece of string you can possibly remove that for example look for ",master" if you find it within "Daily Spendings, master" you could remove it and make the writing bold.

I'm currently using,

```
For x As Integer = 0 To gridCategories.Columns.Count - 1
            If gridCategories.Rows(0).Cells(x).Value.ToString = ",master" Then
                gridCategories.Rows(0).Cells(x).Value.ToString.Replace(",master", "")
            End If
        Next
```

All help is massively appreciated,

Comment: strings are immutable - even if they are in a DGV cell.  so, .Replace is a function returning a *new string value*.  This means you need to assign the result.  Or even better - remove it at the source before it is ever added to the DGV (depending on how the DGV gets the data).

Comment: I've tried using the .Remove function, that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try like this ?

```
For x As Integer = 0 To gridCategories.Rows.Count - 1
    If gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString = ",master" Then
            gridCategories.Rows(x).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Replace(",master", "")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I just need my first column to be checked

Comment: This is the error I have been receiving... "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Contains' accepts this number of arguments."